# How does Netlify CMS dynamically create pull requests?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, netlify, netlify-cms

For example, when a user creates a blog post but does not publish it, how does Netlify CMS create a pull request for the hooked-up Github repo using git gateway?

Answer (score 0):

It stores that post in the browser storage.

Comment: Try to add more information. Try to point out clearly  with specific examples.